# Error when fetchUserProfile from Facebook in SpringSocial

Tags: java, spring, facebook, jackson

I'm using Spring framework in my webserver. The versions of some libraries that I'm using and I think important to say are:

Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE
Spring Social Facebook 2.0.2.RELEASE
Spring Social 1.1.4.RELEASE
Jackson 2.5.3

When I receive the accessToken from Facebook of the login, and I try to [getUserProfile()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/UserOperations.html#getUserProfile()) , I got the following exception:

```
    jan 05, 2016 12:13:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/fr-server] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?fields=id%2Cabout%2Cage_range%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Ccontext%2Ccover%2Ccurrency%2Cdevices%2Ceducation%2Cemail%2Cfavorite_athletes%2Cfavorite_teams%2Cfirst_name%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Cinspirational_people%2Cinstalled%2Cinstall_type%2Cis_verified%2Clanguages%2Clast_name%2Clink%2Clocale%2Clocation%2Cmeeting_for%2Cmiddle_name%2Cname%2Cname_format%2Cpolitical%2Cquotes%2Cpayment_pricepoints%2Crelationship_status%2Creligion%2Csecurity_settings%2Csignificant_other%2Csports%2Ctest_group%2Ctimezone%2Cthird_party_id%2Cupdated_time%2Cverified%2Cvideo_upload_limits%2Cviewer_can_send_gift%2Cwebsite%2Cwork":No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3607)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3547)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.extractErrorFromResponse(FacebookErrorHandler.java:101)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:253)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:53)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:49)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.fetchUserProfile(FacebookAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.fetchUserProfile(FacebookAdapter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.fetchUserProfile(AbstractConnection.java:111)
    at fr.server.login.controller.RegistrationController.registrationFacebook(RegistrationController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not understanding why because my last version was working fine in my website until yesterday. Now this version is getting the same error too. My ID and KEY of Facebook are correct.

Take a look at my code that works in parts:

```
    Connection<Facebook> connection = (Connection<Facebook>) providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(request);
    ConnectionKey providerKey = connection.getKey();

    LOGGER.info("User name {} " , connection.getDisplayName());
    LOGGER.info("User url {} " , connection.getProfileUrl());
    LOGGER.info("Provider {} " , providerKey.getProviderId().toUpperCase());

    /* ERROR HERE IN THESE TWO LINES*/
    LOGGER.info("objeto {} " , connection.fetchUserProfile().toString());   
    LOGGER.info("objeto {} " , connection.getApi().userOperations().getUserProfile().toString());
```

I don't know what to do by now.. I searched but I didn't have success to find a solution. Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: William, if you have the control upon a user, can you check whether the user granted all the necessary privileges?

Comment: Sorry Lajos. I think I didn't understand your question. Which privileges you are talking about? When the user make the login, I get all the data (gender ,birthday, etc) from the profile fetched, and create my User with these data and my permissions (role_user, role_admin, etc).

Comment: Curious fact. The errors occurs only in my Facebook account. I tried others accounts and have been success. Can anyone suggest something? Until yesterday everything was fine . O.o

Comment: William, it might well be that you have something lagging from the former version in your settings. A missing privilege or something. If you really want to know what the problem is, then send a bug report ticket to Facebook. They quickly answer (really). If you want to get rid of the problem, then visit Facebook with your user, go to settings, click on Apps and remove your app from the list by clicking on x. This will make sure that Facebook forgets whatever settings were defined for your specific user and it will be handled like a new user. I still think you have a privilege issue.

Comment: Other curious fact, I created other 'app' on the developer console on Facebook, and I tried to use this new ID and KEY. The problem is the same: in my account is not working, and others accounts are ok!!! That's crazy. I will report to Facebook now. Thanks Lajos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a strange Facebook problem. Facebook is a system which can have bugs, just like any other system. When one sees an anomaly, (s)he should study the case to find out how is Facebook failing to fulfill the expectations. When that is known, one should revise whether his/her expectations are valid. If not, then something about Facebook was learnt and the expectations should be rethought. If yes, then one should think of possible work-arounds while waiting for the issue to be fixed, but, to improve the overall quality of the service, one should report these issues to Facebook. In my experience, Facebook's support is pretty quick.

To apply the idea above to this case, William observed an anomaly. Logically, he tried to fix it and searched for possible causes, since the expectation of his user to be handled just like others seems to be valid. After a while, he reached for people who might experienced the same problem and concluded that this is either a Facebook bug or some setting for his user. In either case, he surely tried to find out what the problem was on his own so it is perfectly valid to send a ticket to Facebook.

Comment: I reported to the Facebook team and the answer is pretty quick really.
My problem was solved yesterday. I didn't nothing in my code and my problem was fixed before the Facebook team help me. It was solved when the guys there was trying to understand the problem. Very strange, but now it's ok.